# Disable Android Support Library ADT: Build: v22.6.2-1085508

Tags: android, eclipse, adt, android-support-library

I am really annoyed at the way the new ADT is working. It has been a week since have started  trying to figure out how to stop Android Support Library from being included into new projects. But even after uninstalling the library, I keep getting the imports into the codes with MainActivity inherting/implementing from ActionBarActivity.

How do I stop this problem??

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I stop this problem?

Do not create an activity when you create the new project. What is adding the extra libraries is the new-activity wizard, both on its own and as integrated in the new-project wizard.

Instead, create your activity classes, resources, and manifest entries by hand, until such time as they provide [other templates that do not require these libraries](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=67513).

Comment: This is enforcement by Google, something I don't like. But thanks anyway.

Comment: @Wajih: FWIW, I just published a "really blank activity" template yesterday that you can use: http://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/15/really-blank-activity-why-appcompat-shoved-down-your-throat.html